# creating a new transparent activity

Tags: android, android-layout

im trying to play a video or show a picture on the phone while still being able to control the phone.
the only thing ive managed to do so far is to start a new transparent activity.
that enables me to show whatever i would like. but i cannot control the phone behind the pic/video.
this is my code:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".VideoPopActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and in the styles.xml:

```
       <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
 <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
```

open to new suggestion aside from this "trick".....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot control an inactive `Activity`, specifically one that is beneath the active one.

What you'll want to do is create a `RelativeLayout` that contains your transparent picture as well as the main layout. This will layer them on top of each other. Make sure both are `match_parent` for both width and height.

```
<RelativeLayout
    ... >

    <LinearLayout
        ... >

        <!-- This is your main layout -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:visibility="gone"
        ... /> <!-- Your picture, invisible by default -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or, instead of an `ImageView`, make another layout, in which you can place your video/image content.

Comment: could u elaborate a bit more? im not sure what to do. my goal is to pop a pic once the alarm clock rings.

Comment: The thing you want to display (video) needs to be part of the same activity that you want to control (the alarm).  You can't have two different activities, where one controls the other.

Comment: @jl Not sure how else to elaborate, here. You need to have both elements in the *same layout*, instead of launching a new `Activity` containing your popup.

Comment: how do i suddenly make the picture visible when the alarm clock rings?

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewId).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`.

Answer (score 0):

This is way to to make activity transparent, however to get more pleasing view, you should make your activity not apaoque, not transparent, as it will give a mirror like or water like view..

you could use,
You should create opaqueStyle.xml in the drawable folder and set your main layout's background as the opaqueStyle.xml..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

<solid android:color="#30646464" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Here in `<solid android:color="#30646464" />` this line, `"#30646464"`, 30 is for opacity, you can increase or decrease its opacity and else six digits are the color, you can adjust it for urself..

Comment: the question was how to pop a picture while still being able to control whatever is behind. for example the alarm clock.

Comment: you cannot control two activities at the same time, creating a transparent activity in front of another activity will make the back activity inactive. you can only control the active activity. However fragments could help to control more than one activity together.

Comment: i agree. have any suggestion on how to show a picture once an alarm goes off, but not by opening a new activity. because then, as u stated  i will not b able to shut the alarm.

Comment: Try using Image Toast, It will definitely do the task, in that you would be able to show a picture in front of activity still having control of activity..